# Ide CLASSPATH vs. system wide CLASSPATH

Tags: java, ide, jar

What's the difference between adding a JAR to the the CLASSPATH of a project in the IDE and adding it to the system wide CLASSPATH?

Comment: It is a bad idea to add a Jar to the system class-path.  Instead it should be added to the class-path of whatever apps. require it.  The more important question for real world apps. is the *compile-time* & *run-time* class-path.

Comment: Ok, so there is a difference in the scope. But if I got this right, there is a even bigger differnce in **when** my applications access those class-path variables. Thus, it's more inportant to know about the **compile-time** and **run-time** class-path, right? What do you mean by »real world« apps. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter is valid for ALL java applications you are running while the former only for the project. 
I'd recommend not using the system wide classpath as things tend to get rather confusing and messy very quickly.

From here:

[PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

> Checking the CLASSPATH variable (All platforms)
>
> The CLASSPATH variable is one way to tell applications, including the
>   JDK tools, where to look for user classes. (Classes that are part of
>   the JRE, JDK platform, and extensions should be defined through other
>   means, such as the bootstrap class path or the extensions directory.)
>
> The preferred way to specify the class path is by using the -cp
>   command line switch. This allows the CLASSPATH to be set individually
>   for each application without affecting other applications. Setting the
>   CLASSPATH can be tricky and should be performed with care.

Comment: The Java Tutorials are interesting, but they only provide information about the System Wide Classpath variable. It doesn't say much about difference between the both.